# Substantive effects too large in linear regression

Tags: regression, econometrics, interpretation, fixed-effects-model

I am running a model where I regress the change in a party's vote share on a party-level policy variable, a country-level variable that counts the number of effective parties in a political system, and an interaction of the two. Change in vote share ranges from -25 to 25, the policy variable ranges from -.28 to .28 and the number of effective parties ranges from 2 to 5.  I run pooled OLS with $n$ parties, $t$ elections and party-level fixed effects with the following model:

$\Delta Vote Share_n = \beta \Delta Policy_n + \beta Parties + \beta (Parties*\Delta Policy_n) + \sum_1^n \beta \delta $

Where $\delta$ are party dummies. I am interested in the marginal effects of the policy variable conditional on the number of parties. When calculating the marginal effects of a one-standard deviation increase in $\Delta Policy$ conditional on different levels of $Parties$, I find nonsensically large effects. For example, the model is telling me that increasing $\Delta Policy$ by one standard deviation when $Parties =3$ results in an increase of 50 percentage points (a party going from 0% of the vote in election 1 to 50% in election 2 or from 25% to 75%).

These effects are much too large and I do not observe these types of swings in my data. I would greatly appreciate any help in figuring out what is causing this. I checked the scaling of the variables and everything seems to look good. Should I use a different type of model? Or should I be using a different quantity to examine the marginal effects?

Comment: What's the size of a standard deviation of your policy variable?

Comment: Standard deviation is about .09.

Comment: It could be that you're trying to extrapolate to a point that is not supported by your data; check if you can find a "typical" range for policy change, rather than the 3 SD. Did you try interaction plots in the spirit of  [Brambor et al.](http://mattgolder.com/files/research/pa_final.pdf)? This should give you an idea about your variable distributions and potential extrapolations.